# git merging from master to local branch

Tags: git, github

If the master has changes ahead of the local branch B1 ( branch created off of old master from previous release ) , then how can I merge changes from master ( latest master ) to local branch B1 ( off of previous master ) which also has local changes different from the latest master on same and/or different files.

```
>> git checkout B1
>> git merge master
```

**Error:**

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in views/index.html
Auto-merging scripts/services/eService.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in scripts/services/eScreenService.js
Auto-merging scripts/directives/confirmService.js
Auto-merging scripts/controllers/submitFormController.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in scripts/controllers/submitFormController.js
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I need to understand how to handle the code conflict in this situation ? How can i revert back the merge changes in the file ( undo `>>>>>>> master` and/or `<<<<<<< HEAD` comments from the file `git revert HEAD{X}` didn't help )

Comment: It's not clear what you meant to do here. A merge conflict (noun) occurs when your changes since the base version conflict (verb) with their changes. For instance, you may have said "paint this box red" and they said "paint this box blue". Git tells you these are not compatible by marking the areas of conflict. It's up to *you* to figure out whether it should be red, blue, purple, or even green, so you should edit the files, find the marked conflicts, figure out what's *correct*, and replace the conflicting sections with correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-revert` Revert some existing commits, no modifications from the HEAD commit. [Git Revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html)

and you have not committed something yet after conflicts.

`git status` is your best friend. it can guide you every second.

```
git status

You have unmerged paths.
(fix conflicts and run "git commit")
(use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)
```

go for

```
git merge --abort
```

this will revert your changes back.

**EDIT**

You can use

```
git checkout --ours file
```

to keep changes of your current branch and remove others. Use **--theirs** for vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, this would only help to revert back to initial local branch state but does't address how to solve the merge conflict.

Comment: This was your question. `How can i revert back the merge changes in the file` which you can do with above command. Git doesn't solve conflicts for you when it occurs in a file. it gives you free hand to edit your file and then `git add` and  `git commit`

Answer (score 2):

You can take a step back: `git merge --abort`

Or you can solve the conflicts manually: `git mergetool` (and then commit your changes)

But you may like another option: [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) will take your changes away, fast forward the upstream branch to your local branch and then re-apply your changes.

Each way is for another situation, so think a little about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `fast forward the upstream branch to your local branch` - does upstream branch means `remote branch` ? if thats the case how does it take update from latest master ?

Comment: "Upstream branch" means technically any branch you choose. (Fetch it if it is remote.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do (when you are in the branch):

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```